# DRF - translation doesn't work on all situations

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-views, django-i18n

DRF translation in my project just translates a part of messages not all of them.
Please see following images: 
In following image, I haven't sent any data for Post request and I've received all error messages translated.

[image]

But in the following image, I've sent some part of data and sent another part invalid. 
As you see, it has not translated message.

[image]

summary:
DRF translates `This field is required`, but it does not translate `Ensure this field has no more than {max_length} characters.`